# elem.colResizable is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, html-table, resize

I am trying to making table column re-sizable in angularjs I am using the the following directive

```
myApp.directive('colResizeable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        elem.colResizable({
          liveDrag: true,
          gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip'></div>",
          draggingClass: "dragging",
          onDrag: function() {
            //trigger a resize event, so width dependent stuff will be updated
            $(window).trigger('resize');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
})
```

and using it in table

```
<table id="tblbody"  col-resizeable >
```

but I am getting an error in the console like this

> elem.colResizable is not a function

```
<head>
     <script src="src/scripts/lib/less/colResizeable.js"></script>
</head>
```

i have added  the resizable plugin also in the head tag as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to load the jQuery library *before* the AngularJS framework.

From the Docs:

> If jQuery is available, `angular.element` is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, `angular.element` delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or **jqLite**.
>
> To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file.
>
> — [AngularJS `angular.element` API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)